# Move element to left javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm co-building a [website](http://dev.lexerim.nl/vin) where we want to use a off-canvas menu for the lesser used menu options. We used [this script](https://github.com/callmenick/Animating-Hamburger-Icons) to add a nice effect to the hamburger menu; works well! But we have a problem, the off-canvas menu slides over the button when clicked so we want the button to move to the left when clicked. Unfortunately targeting the .is-active class with a `margin-right: 600px` doesn't work. Do you guys have any idea? **Note:** The button that get's slide over is in the navbar (top-right) the button called 'hamburger menu' is temporary to work on the menu while the other button is hidden.

---

The button itself uses the following js in which `$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");` makes the off-canvas menu show:

```
(function() {

"use strict";

var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var toggle = toggles[i];
  toggleHandler(toggle);
};

function toggleHandler(toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");

  });
}

 })();
```

Which runs after clicking on the button:
    `<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx pull-right"><span>toggle menu</span></button>`

Comment: show us some code here in SO, don't just use links

Comment: code is far better than words,it helps.Post some code here

Comment: site has too many wrong css..m afraid about the solution will make more changes..

Comment: @Leothelion was some custom font I had to clean out today. Lot better now

Comment: and what about hamburger menu? where you want that button?

Comment: @Leothelion button saying 'hamburger menu' is a temporary button because the button we are using (top right) get's hidden when the off-canavas menu slides in. Thus the button that should move some 300 pixels to the left. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: please be clear with your question so we can help in better way..ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty temporary solution, you could make the hamburger icon appear on top of the menu by applying the below css to the hamburger icon

```
z-index: 2000
```

For a longer term solution, one way would be to add javascript to animate the icon over when the menu is toggled. You could use the jquery animate() command:

```
if (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) {
    $('.c-hamburger').animate({right: '0px'});
else {
    $('.c-hamburger').animate({right: '200px'});
}
```

If you add that to the end of your function toggleHandler(toggle) above it should work

Comment: The z-index works fine for development thanks :). Was trying the long-term solution but the javascript fails whenever I use your else statement. Really weird as I don't see why. Any thoughts? (also, I had to add a ) after the true to get the syntax correct and working)

Comment: Ah it was a small syntax thing, the '}' after the if-statement wasn't there. Fixed now :)